# Ignoring a property in all inherited objects in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, .net-4.0, ef-code-first

I have the following abstract base class for all my entities in my EF code first model:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
  public Id {get; set;}  
  public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}  
  ...
}
```

I wrote following code in my `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating()` method to Ignore the `IsDeleted`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.Ignore("IsDeleted"));
        ...
    }
```

but when it cause following error:

> You cannot use Ignore method on the property 'IsDeleted' on type 'MyEntity' because this type inherits from the type 'BaseEntity' where this property is mapped. To exclude this property from your model, use NotMappedAttribute or Ignore method on the base type.

I'm using `.NET 4` so I couldn't use `[NotMappedAttribute]` to ignore `IsDeleted`, so I used following code:

```
public partial class BaseEntity_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity> 
{
    public BaseEntity_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Ignore(t => t.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

and updated the `OnCreatingModel()` method to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BaseEntity_Mapping());
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.Ignore("IsDeleted"));
    ...
}
```

but the problem exists yet.
Is there any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in the Entity Framework 5. See [this link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/481).

It should have been fixed in EF6.
As a workaround: make `IsDeleted` readonly and provide a `SetIsDeleted(bool value)` function.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in 6.1.3.